# Adding CSS or JS file to MediaWiki?

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

I've been following some tutorials at mediawiki.org but I didn't make it. I need to add a new CSS or JS code to be available in all my wiki (basically be cause I need to add some div tags).

Can you guys help me?

Appreciate that.

Comment: Which tutorial? Where did you struggle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614085/1333493 applies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can edit the CSS or JS files used by your wiki at the page names:

```
MediaWiki:Common.css
MediaWiki:Common.js
```

For instance, here is [the Common.css used by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css).

There are also similar pages used for specific themes. For instance, if your wiki is using the Vector theme, you can place code specific to that theme at:

```
MediaWiki:Vector.css
MediaWiki:Vector.js
```

Editing any of these pages will require admin rights.

Comment: logged as root:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /mediawiki/MediaWiki:Common.css on this server.

Comment: That is not a MediaWiki error message. Either you don't have it set up correctly, or you're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to reuse and extend an existing MediaWiki theme, you do not need to add a new CSS file. It is much easier.

Suppose your Wiki is running on mywiki.local/wiki/, and we use the Vector skin.

Now all you have to do, is to open mywiki.local/wiki/MediaWiki:Vector.css and add the styles for the DIVs you add to pages.

The real question here is: do you plan to modify the skin itself, or do you just plan to add your own DIVs into Wiki pages? Anyway, in both cases you can edit the skin CSS via MediaWiki to avoid hacking around in the file system - which breaks with each update.

Avoid editing MediaWiki files at any cost, upgrades become painful that way.

If you want to make styles for your DIVs in pages available to all MediaWiki skins, you have to edit mywiki.local/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css. Changes made here are applied to all skins.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I had to modify the `/skins/Vector.php` and `/skins/vector/main.css` files. Could you explain in more detail what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to add a new CSS page to my mediawiki project, a file where to edit my divs and tables.