# Mediawiki adding custom javascript / Editing Common.js

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I need to add one line of custom js to my wiki that will apply to everyone. What line do i need to append to LocalSettings.php to enable modification of Mediawiki:Common.js (and Mediawiki:Common.css)? None of the following work:

```
$wgUseSiteJs = true;
$wgUserSiteJs = true;
$wgAllowUserJs = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edituserjs'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['editusercssjs'] = true;
```

I also scoured every file in my installation of mediawiki for the string "Any JavaScript here will be loaded for all users on every page load", but nothing showed up so i dont know how to directly edit Common.js either.

I could create an extension, but that seems like total overkill for one line of code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding CSS or JS file to MediaWiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775095/adding-css-or-js-file-to-mediawiki)

Comment: I already know how to get to the pages. I just cant edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the following query in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT user_id INTO @uid FROM user 
WHERE user_name = '<USER YOURE LOGGED IN AS>' LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO `user_groups`(`ug_user`, `ug_group`)
VALUES (@uid,'bureaucrat'),(@uid,'sysop');
```