# Easiest way to run page-specific JavaScript on MediaWiki and/or SMW

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki up and running, and I added SemanticMediaWiki to be able to do some more stuff. Now I want the data that I added using SMW to generate some fancy graphics using JavaScript. My problem is as follows.

I can't find much in the way of information how to embed JavaScript in MediaWiki.

In my case, all I need is a way to call a JavaScript, that picks up an array from the ask array (SMW), take that data to generate some boxes with links and throw some CSS at it.

So far I haven't even figured out a way of running it (other than throwing it in common.js, which isn't awfully helpful).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614085/1333493 applies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "page-specific". If you want to run this JS only on one page, you can simply add to your Common.js something like

```
if ( mw.config.get( 'wgPageName' ) === 'Pagename' ) {
    [dostuff]
}
```

If you want to leverage [ResourceLoader](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader) (please read, that's the main entry point for MediaWiki JavaScript docs), what about a [gadget](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets)?

Comment: Great simple solution, except of course your if-statement will be executed on *every* page. Would be great if you could share steps using a gadget :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up writing an article on how to do it. So if anyone else want to do something similar, this is one option.

https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/How_to_write_a_JavaScript_to_display_data_in_a_Semantic_MediaWiki