# How to add css and js files to mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to install a new javascript script on my wiki.

So I have to call this following scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="library/pretty-json-master/css/pretty-json.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/pretty-json-master/libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/pretty-json-master/libs/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/pretty-json-master/libs/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/pretty-json-master/pretty-json-debug.js"></script>
```

What is the best practice to add this on all my pages ?

Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding css file to mediawiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775095/adding-css-file-to-mediawiki)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614085/1333493 applies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1/ Create a new extension in "extensions" folder (extensions/jsonTree/)

2/ Create a php file in this folder (jsonTree.php)

```
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = 'onBeforePageDisplay';

function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin ) {

    $script = '
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/extensions/jsonTree/modules/css/pretty-json.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extensions/jsonTree/modules/libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extensions/jsonTree/modules/libs/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extensions/jsonTree/modules/libs/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extensions/jsonTree/modules/pretty-json-debug.js"></script>
    ';

    $out->addHeadItem("jsonTree script", $script);

    return true;

}
```

3/ Include this file in LocalSettings.php

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/jsonTree/jsonTree.php" );
```

Comment: That's the worst way you can do it in a MediaWiki extension. This bypasses the ResourceLoader, which takes care about a lot of useful things, read https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Features and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader to know, how to develop an extension with the ResourceLoader. You can add a module with `$out->addModules()` in your `onBeforePageDisplay` hook handler.

Answer (score -1):

There might be other ways, but you could create a light MediaWiki extension which only sets `$wgResourceModules`. See [Manual:$wgResourceModules](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceModules).

Comment: Ok thanks but I don't know where I have to call the $this->getOutput()->addModules( 'ext.myExtension' );

Comment: Follow-up in [Where to call addModules()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626025/where-to-call-addmodules). Other options (I would say they are worse): load it from a [global script file](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript), use [gadgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets).