# Where to call addModules()?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I would like to add some scripts and styles to all my wiki pages.
So I have create the file /extensions/MyExtension/MyExtension.php and I put a following array like this:

```
$wgResourceModules['ext.MyExtension.foo'] = array(
    'scripts' => 'modules/ext.MyExtension.foo.js',
    'styles' => array('modules/ext.MyExtension.foo.css','modules/ext.MyExtension.bar.css'),
    'localBasePath' => __DIR__,
    'remoteExtPath' => 'MyExtension',
);
```

But in the documentation they say that I have to call

```
 $this->getOutput()->addModules( 'ext.myExtension' );
```

but I don't know where I have to call it.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would implement the [BeforePageDisplay](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforePageDisplay) hook and use the OutputPage object received there.